# Search String in Cell Efficient Way

Tags: string, matlab, search, cell

It's my first post here, so please bear with me :-).

Problem Background:
I've multiple text files of the form:

```
<ticker>,<date>,<open>,<high>,<low>,<close>,<vol>
A,20120904 0926,37.14,37.14,37.14,37.14,693
.
.
.
ZZ,20120904 1602,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,11771
```

As you might have guessed it's stock ticks. When I load it to matlab, it creates a structure with an array (of the numerical values) and a cell (for the strings) which is fine at this point as I can work with it.
Problem:

I'd like to find the most efficient way to search the array for a specific symbol (~70K lines). While it's easy to do a naive or halving searches, I don't think these approaches are very useful for multiple files and/or multiple searches to extract the beginning and end indices of a given symbol/string. 
I've looked into past posts here and read about Rabin-Karp, Bitap and hash tables, but I'm not sure any of them fully answers my needs.

So far, I've leaning towards running through the cell once and creating a hash table for each letter (i.e. 'A', 'B', etc) and then running a naive search or anything else you might suggest :-). The reason for hashing is that I might use the same file to look up different stock symbols, so I think running through it once and labeling letters will reduce the complexity in the long run.

What are your thoughts on the matter? Am I in the right direction? 
I'm using matlab btw.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your tickers in a struct array. Each column being a property. Assuming you have non-empty values, you can do the following,

```
tickers = [S.tickers];
dates = [S.date];
```

You can easily do queries to get the index you want from your struct array S. You can go further and index tickers by ticker name, by creating an index with ticker name as keys.